# Wait for SSIS job to be executed

Tags: ssis, powershell-2.0

I am using below code to run ssis jobs from SSIS which is working fine, but I want that after running the job it should wait for the job to finish and then proceed further

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") |Out-Null;
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server]$sqlServer = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $HostName;

if([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($sqlServer.Urn))
{
    Write-Host "`nThe hostname provided is not a valid SQL Server instance.  Did you mistype the alias or forget to add the instance name?`n";
    Exit;
}
else
{ 
    [String]$databaseInstance = $sqlServer.JobServer.Urn.Value.Substring($sqlServer.JobServer.Urn.Value.IndexOf("'") + 1, `
    $sqlServer.JobServer.Urn.Value.IndexOf("'", ($sqlServer.JobServer.Urn.Value.IndexOf("'")) `
        - ($sqlServer.JobServer.Urn.Value.IndexOf("'"))));
}

Write-Host "Enumerating jobs on server ...";

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.Job]$job = ($sqlServer.JobServer.Jobs | ? { $_.Name -eq $JobName });

if($job -eq $null)
{
    Write-Host "`nNo such job on the server.`n";
    Exit;
}

# Finally invoke the job.  Use the job history (in SSMS) to verify the success of the job.
Write-Host "Executing job (the script doesn't wait for the job to finish but it should)...`n`n";
$job.Start();
```

How can I wait after *$job.Start(); to see the job is completed so that I can proceed further?

I am executing below code but it is not working properly, any help ?

```
   [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo")

$server = new-object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" "ServerName"
$job = $server.JobServer.Jobs["YourJobName"]
$now = Get-Date
do
{
 Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
 $job.Refresh()
 $jobstat = $job | select CurrentRunStatus
 $stat = $jobstat.CurrentRunStatus
 WRITE-HOST $stat
}

while($stat -eq "Executing")

$job | select Name,CurrentRunStatus,LastRunDate
```

Comment: I don't know powershell, but can't you write a loop that waits (sleeps) for n- seconds and then queries the job history table to see if the job is completed?  Keep looping until it gets the result that the job is completed.

Comment: If you have a task that must wait on the first job to finish, why not just make it a second task in the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting a SQL Agent job is an an asynchronous event. You don't have the ability to get progress messages pushed back to you. As Tab Alleman has commented, you'll need to poll the msdb job tables to determine whether the agent is still running.

That said, do you *need* to launch the jobs via agent? If you're just running a package, use the API to start the package and watch the events until it completes/fails/etc.

Comment: meanwhile, I have coded this

     # Load Assemblies
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo")
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") 
     
    $server = new-object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" "server"
    $job = $server.JobServer.Jobs[$JobName]
    $now = Get-Date        
    $jobstat = $job | select CurrentRunStatus

        If($jobstat -eq 'running'){ 
            WRITE-HOST 'Job is running' #YET TO CODE 
            }